# Apche NiFi Not Working

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

I just started learning about Apache NIFI. I installed it by following this video on youtube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDd6KayUHt8

I blindly followed what he said. But when I type http://localhost:9090/nifi (as said on the video) on the browser. Nothing works.

I get this error in command prompt -

[image: Error]
I tried googling for solution but couldn't find any. Someone please help.

Comment: That message does not necessarily indicate a failure, rather that we don't have a certainty over process ID given the Windows environment.  Could you evaluate the nifi-app.log and nifi-bootstrap.log in the logs directory of your installation to see if anything is of interest there?

Comment: Open your nifi.properties file check what's the port set for `nifi.web.http.port` and use that port. Also please take a look at your log files: nifi-app.log and nifi-bootstrap.log

Comment: The nifi.web.http.port is set to 8080. 
I checked nifi-app.log and I get this exception-->
java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address

2018-04-05 08:05:43,205 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.

Answer (score 4):

Try http://localhost:8080/nifi, or match the correct port from the conf/nifi.properties file:

```
nifi.web.http.port=8080
```

Comment: I tried. Its Still not working. I get some --> java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address Error.

Answer (score 0):

change the port number in nifi.properties file in conf file.open with the changed port number
http://localhost:**changed port number**/nifi

Comment: I tried. Its Still not working. I get some --> java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address Error.

Comment: if you are using 8080 as your port number then you want to change that port to some unused port on your server.                                                                                                  Below link have some solution regarding your problem       http://apache-nifi-developer-list.39713.n7.nabble.com/NiFi-1-5-0-can-t-start-with-AWS-public-ip-is-set-to-nifi-web-https-host-td17962.html